# Dynamic output files from list variable in nextflow

Tags: groovy, nextflow

I have a very simple nextflow process, it takes as an input a list of files (can be 1 or 2) and what I want is out output a list of files equal to the input with a modification:

```
process filtering{

        input:
        tuple val(acc),  path(fastqlist)

        output:
        tuple val(acc), path(filtered_fastqlist)

        script:
            def filtered_fastqlist = (fastqlist.size() == 2) ? ["fastp_"+fastqlist[0],"fastp_"+fastqlist[1]] : ["fastp_"+fastqlist[0]]

            """
            touch  ${filtered_fastqlist[0]}
            touch  ${filtered_fastqlist[1]}
            """
}
```

When running this, nextflow gives me the error `NOTE: Missing output file(s) 'filtered_fastqlist' expected by process`.
It seemss somehow that filtered_fastq is being used as a literal, instead of a groovy array. (I know I could just use a wildcard), but is there anyway to dynamically pass a list of values from a variable to a an output channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `def` keyword makes the variable context inaccessible (different scope) to the output block. Check the snippet below for another example. Try adding `def` to run into the same error you did.

```
process filtering{
  input:
  tuple val(acc),  path(fastqlist)

  output:
  tuple val(acc), path(my_str)

  script:
  my_str = fastqlist.find { it.toString().endsWith('2.txt') }
  """
  """
}

workflow {
  Channel
    .of(['A', [file('A1.txt'), file('A2.txt'), file('A3.txt')]],
        ['B', [file('B1.txt'), file('B2.txt'), file('B3.txt')]])
    | filtering
    | view
}
```

Outputs with and without the `def` keyword.
[image]

Comment: "The def keyword makes the variable context inaccessible (different scope) to the output block." Thanks for this explanation, the scoping of variables with/without `def` might be one of the more confusing things about nextflow scripting